# Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages'

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, installation

Good afternoon, please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I just installed the Linux Ubuntu on my computer and still don’t understand anything about it. I tried to install PostreSQL and pgAdmin. I installed on this video tutorial `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vdzb7JTPnGk` I get this error.

Text of Error: `Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'`

[image]

Tell me please how to fix it.
My version of ubuntu: `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`

Comment: The instructions you are using, are from 2012, when it wasn't uncommon to have i386 and x86_64 packages. Clean up your PPA list by removing the one you added for PGDG and use the instructions from here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @KevinBBurns you will get the same error if you follow [the official](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) instructions. The default repositories in Ubuntu 20.04 also don't have pgadmin4.

Comment: @IvanIvanov having the same issue since upgraded to 20.04, did you find the solution?

Comment: Looks like there is a solution to similar here: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x)

Comment: Indeed, @PramodShinde — and AskUbuntu has lots of similar questions, for many different packages, all of them can be fixed using `[arch=amd64]`, as [answered below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61550008/1035977).

Answer (score 301):

You must change the line of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` to

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

Comment: this statement won't show any warning message anymore with postgresql 13 - ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @sitthykun are you sure about that? I just tried with a fresh install of 20.04 since pgsql 14 was released and it DOES fail. While I do love the debian and postgresql ecosystems, I sure wish they would at least add a note to the docs for this. For many years this has created unnecessary friction for the world's most used distro. Just because of debian ego issues...

Comment: For those people "as dummy" as me, when you say "change that line" it refers to:
`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`. After log-in as a superuser, a txt file will appear and you have to replace the line in your txt by the commented line here:
`deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main`.
It worked for me with a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: For those who may have stumbled upon this issue via Google... the same trick will also work fine with the source packages for [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/) under Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: What if I don't have the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` ? Neither in that location nor anywhere? I have archive files for the package in question... should I delete those and try re-adding the deb?

Comment: Edit: looks like you can delete the bad deb source and re-add it using the [arch=amd64] section, per the code line in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that `focal` refers to a particular Ubuntu version (20.x). Make sure to use the right one. Ubuntu 22 is `jammy`, for example I already had this: `deb  http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main` in `pgdg.list` so I just added the `[arch=amd64]` after `deb`

Comment: How about fixing the root cause, apt runing on a 64 bit machine ignoring repos that dont support i386? Is that not an issue with apt not the package installation?

Answer (score 97):

**Run** this command to find a **/pgdg.list** file

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

**Find** the line:

```
*deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main*
```

And **change** it to:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main
```

**SAVE** file and **RUN**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This worked wonders - care to explain what the introduced change did?

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 22):

Run below command:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

and **replace** this line:

```
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
```

with

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

**save and exit** with `wq`.

Comment: Verified working for ubuntu 20, postgresql 9.6.

Answer (score 14):

Run:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Change the line of :

```
http://apt.postgresql...
```

with:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

Save and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @hmdbbgh is correct. But how would you add the "arch=amd64" to the line if there's already braces pointing to a gpg keyring signature?

I found this question while searching for a solution to the same error happening with the Brave browser and I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm):

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I went to the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
ls
```

And there I found the brave-browser-release.list file.
I like to edit with pluma, so I opened it up:

```
sudo pluma brave-browser-release.list
```

The line to be edited in the brave-browser-release.list file had braces with gpg signing info, so I was unsure how to add the [arch=amd64]:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
```

I tried it a couple of ways and the solution was to add the entry

`arch=amd64`

after the signed-by entry, separated by a space. So the complete entry now looks like:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
```

If you're unsure about making changes, you can backup the file first. You can also just make a new line and comment out the original line, like this:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
# deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
```

And of course, save it and run another update to see if it fixed your issue.

```
sudo apt update
```