# microsoft package - Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages'

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, kinect, apt

I am trying to install azure kinect on Ubuntu 18.04 following the instructions here https://scazlab.github.io/azure_setup_guide.html. I ran these lines of code

```
curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod
sudo apt-get update
```

and got the error message below

```
(base) kong@kong-Standard:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.humanoids.kit.edu/bionic/main bionic InRelease           
Hit:3 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                     
Hit:4 http://packages.humanoids.kit.edu/bionic/testing bionic InRelease        
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease        
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:11 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (220 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I found the solution to similar problem at this thread [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523447/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages)
but in my case, I am not able to find the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list`

Comment: find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the folder `/etc/apt/`, where you have the *folder* `source.list.d`, you should also have a *file* called `source.list`.

Check if your package is there, and modify the corresponding line as needed.

```bash
cd /etc/apt/
cat sources.list
```

You should have a line like
`https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic main` somewhere probably towards the end.

Modify the file, using nano for example :

```bash
sudo nano sources.list
```

and add the mention `[arch=amd64]`:

```bash
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic main
```